# How to create custom add object to NSSet method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I wan't to customize the add object to NSSet method, which is created from Core Data. I don't really know where can I add the given paramater to my NSSet `self.comments` now.

```
- (void)addCommentsObject:(Comment *)value
{
    if (value.liked)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }

    // how should I add the object to self.comments

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make `self.comments` a `NSMutableSet` and then you can use `addObject:` on it;

or

Create temporary set add object to it and save as `self.comments`, in code

```
- (void)addCommentsObject:(Comment *)value
{
     if (value)
     {
        NSMutableSet * mSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithSet:self.comments];
        [mSet addObject:value];
        self.comments = mSet.set;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend not always creating a new set, but rather checking to see if mSet is already mutable and only creating and copying it if needed.

Comment: @David, agree, but in real project I prefer make this property mutable  rather that creating copy to add objects